# Decreasing magnitude of spherical centroid (simplex version)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, spherical-geometry, geometric-inequalities

Let $\sigma$ be the uniform measure on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$. For any region $R\subset \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, let $X_R$ be a random variable which is uniformly distributed across $R$. We have $$E(X_R)=\frac{1}{\sigma(R)}\int_R xd\sigma (x)$$
Is it true that if $R\subset S\subset \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ are spherical simplices then $|E(X_S)|\le |E(X_R)|$?

To start, I'll state a claim that might be helpful.

**Claim**: If $T\subset \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ with $G=E(X_T)/|E(X_T)|$ and $B$ is a small ball $B$ disjoint from $T$, then $|E(X_{T\cup B})|<|E(X_T)|$ iff $B$ is further (by dot product) from $G$ than the rest of $T$, on average. That is, for $b\in B$

$$G\cdot b<\frac{1}{\sigma(T)}\int_T G\cdot xd\sigma(x)$$

> **Proof of claim**: Note that for positive numbers $a,b,c,d$ satisfying $a/b<c/d$, $$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+c}{b+d}< \frac{c}{d}$$ Also, when $B$ is small, $$\frac{E(X_{T\cup B})}{|E(X_{T\cup B})|}\approx \frac{E(X_T)}{|E(X_T)|}=:G$$ so that $|E(X_T)|=G\cdot E(X_T)$ and $|E(X_{T\cup B})|\approx G\cdot E(X_{T\cup B})$. Expanding these out, the statement $|E(X_{T\cup B})|<|E(X_T)|$ becomes \begin{align*}\frac{\int_T G\cdot x d\sigma(x)+\int_B G\cdot x d\sigma(x)}{\sigma(T)+\sigma(B)}<&\frac{\int_T G\cdot x d\sigma(x)}{\sigma(T)}\\ \frac{\int_B G\cdot xd\sigma(x)}{\sigma(B)}<&\frac{\int_T G\cdot x d\sigma(x)}{\sigma(T)}\\ G\cdot b <& \frac{\int_T G\cdot xd\sigma(x)}{\sigma(T)}\end{align*} All the steps are reversible, so we have both directions of iff. One direction still works for any small region $B$ disjoint from $T$, but the other direction fails as the magnitude $|\int_B xd\sigma(x)|/\sigma(B)$ can be significantly less than $1$.

Comment: Same story, unfortunately, but now in $R^3$ instead of $R^2$. Take the long planar rectangle and rotate one of the short sides so that it becomes perpendicular to the original plane. Now take the diamond and move the short diagonal out of the plane a bit. You'll get two simplices in $R^3$ approximating an interval but with different averages of $|x-c|^2$ where $c$ is the center of mass (in both cases it is close to the middle of the interval by symmetry). Each of them can be put inside the other one again and "whoosh, fly all our hopes away...".

Comment: Ah, it seems I'm sunk :)

Thanks for your keen insights. Just a guess, are you Fedor Nazarov?

Comment: Alas, just his pale shadow by now (sigh!). After 50 the brain merely refuses to function properly...